# How to make a regression with many data frames

Tags: r, regression

I have data about gender and petitioning. I want to make a regression between the "Femme" (woman) variable and the different issues of the petitions. I have regrouped those issues into data frames under general themes, and those themes are what I want to regress with the "Femme" (woman) variable.

P.S.: Some petitions have many issues (ex.: water + science). So one petition could be counted in two data frames at the same time.

1) Here is what I did for all issues, this one is an example with the "Aboriginal" issue to show you how I coded the initial issues (you can also see the "Femme" variable at the beginning, which is already coded "0" and "1" in the original dataset under "Female"):

```
DataPetitions$Femme <- DataPetitions$Female
DataPetitions$Aboriginal <- NA
DataPetitions$Aboriginal[grepl("Aboriginal", DataPetitions$Issue)] <-1 
DataPetitions$Aboriginal[!grepl("Aboriginal", DataPetitions$Issue)] <-0
# ... (same for all 24 specific issues)
```

2) Creating 7 data frames for general petitioning themes:

```
EnvironmentalIssues <- c(DataPetitions$AirQuality,DataPetitions$Biological, DataPetitions$Climate, DataPetitions$Environmental, DataPetitions$Toxic, DataPetitions$Waste, DataPetitions$Water)
EconomicIssues <- c(DataPetitions$Natural, DataPetitions$Transport) 
SocialIssues <- c(DataPetitions$Aboriginal, DataPetitions$Health)   
AgriculturalIssues <- c(DataPetitions$Agriculture,
DataPetitions$Fisheries, DataPetitions$Pesticides)    
PoliticalIssues <- c(DataPetitions$Compliance, DataPetitions$Federal,
DataPetitions$Governance, DataPetitions$International)    
ScientificIssues <- c(DataPetitions$Science)
OtherIssues <- c(DataPetitions$Other)
```

3) Trying to do a regression. This is my glm code:

```
model7 <- glm(DataPetitions$Femme ~ SocialIssues + PoliticalIssues +
ScientificIssues + EnvironmentalIssues + EconomicIssues +
AgriculturalIssues + OtherIssues, data = DataPetitions)

# When I try to run it, I get this error message: 

Error in model.frame.default(formula = DataPetitions$Femme ~
SocialIssues +  :    variable lengths differ (found for
'SocialIssues')
```

With `dput(head(DataPetitions,20))`, I get this:

```
 [...] class = "factor"), Femme = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), AuMoinsUneFemme = c(1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
    Homme = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 2), AuMoinsUnHomme = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Individual1 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), Group1 = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
    Organisation1 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), Aboriginal = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), Agriculture = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
    AirQuality = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), Biological = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Climate = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), Compliance = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Environmental = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Federal = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Fisheries = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), Governance = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Health = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), International = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Natural = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Other = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Pesticides = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Science = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Toxic = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Transport = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Waste = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), Water = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Data.", "Title", "Number",  "Issue", "Petitioner", "Individual", "Group", "Organisation", 
"Female", "Male", "Unknown", "DateReceived", "Status", "Summary", 
"Hyperlink", "Femme", "AuMoinsUneFemme", "Homme", "AuMoinsUnHomme", 
"Individual1", "Group1", "Organisation1", "Aboriginal", "Agriculture",
"AirQuality", "Biological", "Climate", "Compliance", "Environmental", 
"Federal", "Fisheries", "Governance", "Health", "International", 
"Natural", "Other", "Pesticides", "Science", "Toxic", "Transport", 
"Waste", "Water"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: when you use `c()`it creates a vector where the first half will be the column `Natural`(for example) then the column `Transport`so it will be twice as long as the column `Femme`. Depending on what you want you can sum Natural and Transport so that you have one variable (but that doesn't make much sense to sum them) or you can use `cbind`to create a dataframe with 2 columns. The best thing would be to have only one dataframe with one column `Femme`and one column for each other variable.

Comment: From the look of your dataframe I guess you can already do `glm(Femme~.,data=DataPetitions)`if you want to use all the columns. Otherwise replace the `.`with Science+Other+International+...

Comment: Thanks for your answers! However, when I do what you just said in your last comment, I get an error message (see last code text of my question). And I wouldn't know how to "have only one dataframe with one column Femme and one column for each other variable" as you suggested unfortunately.

Comment: Please give us the output of `dput(DataPetitions)` or of  `dput(head(DataPetitions,20))` if your initial dataframe is huge so that we may better help you. For a regression, the variables must all have the same length (you can use `dim` or `length` to access it) otherwise it will return your error.

Comment: I just added it to the initial text question! I assume you need the last part (the rest being huge - even too huge to be copy-pasted in the console).

Comment: Ok a few thinks to help you : you have only binary variables so you probably need to use a probit or a logit model in your glm function otherwise the results won't make sense. Given that your explanatory variables are discrete your should use factor variables. And if you are (as I think) trying to determine if the people who answered is a male or no in function of the variables it seems strange that for some rows male=female=1. But that aside look at ?glm to select the best family to use and at ?factor to know how to deal with factor variables. And don't sum your variables.